# git branch tab autocomplete does not show proper branch names

Tags: git

When I log into a remote computer and enter (inside the git repo)

```
$git branch <TAB>
FETCH_HEAD   HEAD         ORIG_HEAD
```

But I know the output should be (and this what I get on my personal computer)..

```
$git branch <TAB>
alternative_fftxlib          origin/pw-kli                qe-5.2.1
develop                      PW-1.2.0                     qe-5.3
FETCH_HEAD                   PW-1.3.0                     qe-5.4
HEAD                         PW-1.3.1                     qe-6.0.0
```

So it seems that my remote computer has something off with the git settings but I can't figure out why I"m seeing all the branches properly on my personal computer but not my remote one...

Comment: Is the "remote computer" one that you are using as a `git remote`, or is it just a box that has another clone of the repo?  What does `git branch -l` return on the remote box?

Comment: the "remote computer" is a separate clone of the same repository. `git branch -l` returns: `* master`